# Vim. Troubles with encoding on file saved in windows

Tags: windows, vim, encoding

I have ��� chars after each time I save file in windows for some folders. And for some other folders - all is fine. I can't find difference between folders where everything is fine and folders where files saving with bad endings. So I have to run `dos2unix` in my linux virtual machine on modified files every time. Since these files is `javascript` - it's very annoying!

Help me, where to dig? How to avoid appearing of ��� chars at the end of file?

`:set fileencoding=utf-8` does not help.

Usually vim has for dos files - `[dos]` label at the bottom of buffer window - in my case all is fine, and no `[dos]` label there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks more like a file format problem than encoding. I recommend adding this to your `~/_vimrc`:

```
set fileformat=unix
set fileformats=unix,dos
set nobinary
```

You can find more details in `:help fileformat`

Comment: You just saved huge amount of my time. I should ask about this before! Thanks!

Comment: hmmm.. now sometimes it saves file partially.. is it another question?

Comment: uhhh... never seen that happen... How do you mean exactly? Saves only first N bytes or how...?

Comment: dos2unix can fix something that was deleted?? Wow that's an intelligent program :) If dos2unix fixes it, then bytes were not really cut off, they just became "invisible" to you somehow, maybe due to some funny characters before them. Maybe you can play with `set binary` to see all strange characters.

Comment: now it's not working again... can't get idea why.  `set binary` does not help, `set fileformat=unix` does not help, but on save it adds `[unix]` label.

Comment: since I've never seen this it's hard to help too... When you play with `fileformat` also be mindful of `fileformats` (plural!) and read the `:help` well. And some of these settings don't take effect on the current buffer, so if you make changes then kill the current buffer and `:edit` the file again. You might also want to make sure that some `autocmd` don't mess with your settings. In any case I'm pretty much out of ideas... (in any case I don't see how it can be related to virtualbox)